# Keikai having black screen after upgrade

Tags: spreadsheet

I have been trying out keikai spreadsheet for a while, however after upgrading to beta 16 it shows up only black screen, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please open chrome developer tool (F12) / Console tab to check of there is an error message like:
`TypeError: 1.25: type 'minified:E6' is not a subtype of type 'int'`

Please also check your screen display setting or browser zoom, if you set them other than 100%. Keikai can't render itself correctly.

But this bug was fixed, please upgrade to **1.0.0-beta.19**.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Yes, I was not at 100%, after I changed the zoom level it worked!